# Wicket, Spring and Hibernate - Testing with Unitils - Error: Table not found in statement [select relname from pg_class]

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, junit, wicket

I've been following a tutorial and a sample application, namely 5 Days of Wicket - Writing the tests: http://www.mysticcoders.com/blog/2009/03/10/5-days-of-wicket-writing-the-tests/

I've set up my own little project with a simple shoutbox that saves messages to a database. I then wanted to set up a couple of tests that would make sure that if a message is stored in the database, the retrieved object would contain the exact same data.

Upon running *mvn test* all my tests fail. The exception has been pasted in the first code box underneath. I've noticed that even though my unitils.properties says to use the 'hdqldb'-dialect, this message is still output in the console window when starting the tests: *INFO - Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect*. I've added the entire dump from the console as well at the bottom of this post (which goes on for miles and miles :-)).

Upon running *mvn test* all my tests fail, and the exception is:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [select relname from pg_class]
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:188)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:151)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.(DatabaseMetadata.java:69)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.(DatabaseMetadata.java:62)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean$3.doInHibernate(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:958)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
 ... 49 more
```

I've set up my unitils.properties file like so:

```
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

database.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:PUBLIC
database.userName=sa
database.password=

database.dialect=hsqldb

database.schemaNames=PUBLIC
```

My abstract IntegrationTest class:

```
@SpringApplicationContext({"/com/upbeat/shoutbox/spring/applicationContext.xml", "applicationContext-test.xml"})
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {
 private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
}
```

applicationContext-test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.unitils.database.UnitilsDataSourceFactoryBean"/>
</beans>
```

and finally, one of the test classes:

```
package com.upbeat.shoutbox.web;

import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.test.AnnotApplicationContextMock;
import org.apache.wicket.util.tester.WicketTester;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.unitils.spring.annotation.SpringBeanByType;

import com.upbeat.shoutbox.HomePage;
import com.upbeat.shoutbox.integrations.AbstractIntegrationTest;
import com.upbeat.shoutbox.persistence.ShoutItemDao;
import com.upbeat.shoutbox.services.ShoutService;

public class TestHomePage extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{
 @SpringBeanByType
 private ShoutService svc;

 @SpringBeanByType
 private ShoutItemDao dao;

 protected WicketTester tester;

 @Before
 public void setUp()
 {
  AnnotApplicationContextMock appctx = new AnnotApplicationContextMock();

  appctx.putBean("shoutItemDao", dao);
  appctx.putBean("shoutService", svc);
  tester = new WicketTester();
 }

 @Test
 public void testRenderMyPage()
 {
  //start and render the test page
  tester.startPage(HomePage.class);

  //assert rendered page class
  tester.assertRenderedPage(HomePage.class);

  //assert rendered label component
  tester.assertLabel("message", "If you see this message wicket is properly configured and running");
 }
}
```

Dump from console when running *mvn test*:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building shoutbox
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: F:\Projects\shoutbox\target\surefire-reports
INFO  - ConfigurationLoader        - Loaded main configuration file unitils-default.properties from classpath.
INFO  - ConfigurationLoader        - Loaded custom configuration file unitils.properties from classpath.
INFO  - ConfigurationLoader        - No local configuration file unitils-local.properties found.

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.upbeat.shoutbox.web.TestViewShoutsPage
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.02 sec 
INFO  - Version                    - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
INFO  - Environment                - Hibernate 3.3.0.SP1
INFO  - Environment                - hibernate.properties not found
INFO  - Environment                - Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO  - Environment                - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO  - Version                    - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
INFO  - AnnotationBinder           - Binding entity from annotated class: com.upbeat.shoutbox.models.ShoutItem
INFO  - QueryBinder                - Binding Named query: item.getById => from ShoutItem item where item.id = :id
INFO  - QueryBinder                - Binding Named query: item.find => from ShoutItem item order by item.timestamp desc
INFO  - QueryBinder                - Binding Named query: item.count => select count(item) from ShoutItem item
INFO  - EntityBinder               - Bind entity com.upbeat.shoutbox.models.ShoutItem on table SHOUT_ITEMS
INFO  - AnnotationConfiguration    - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO  - notationSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO  - earchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
INFO  - ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - RDBMS: HSQL Database Engine, version: 1.8.0
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC driver: HSQL Database Engine Driver, version: 1.8.0
INFO  - Dialect                    - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO  - TransactionFactoryFactory  - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
INFO  - actionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC batch size: 1000
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Connection release mode: auto
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query cache: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
INFO  - FactoryCacheProviderBridge - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query cache factory: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCacheFactory
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Echoing all SQL to stdout
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Statistics: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Named query checking : enabled
INFO  - SessionFactoryImpl         - building session factory
INFO  - essionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO  - UpdateTimestampsCache      - starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
INFO  - StandardQueryCache         - starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
INFO  - notationSessionFactoryBean - Updating database schema for Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO  - Dialect                    - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
INFO  - SQLErrorCodesFactory       - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3e0ebb: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,shoutService,shoutItemDao,wicketApplication,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  - sPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@a8e586: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@a8e586]; startup date [Tue May 04 18:19:58 CEST 2010]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/upbeat/shoutbox/spring/applicationContext.xml]
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=close; defined in class path resource [com/upbeat/shoutbox/spring/applicationContext.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.unitils.database.UnitilsDataSourceFactoryBean]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]]
INFO  - sPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@a8e586]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5dfaf1
INFO  - pertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5dfaf1: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,shoutService,shoutItemDao,wicketApplication,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  - AnnotationBinder           - Binding entity from annotated class: com.upbeat.shoutbox.models.ShoutItem
INFO  - QueryBinder                - Binding Named query: item.getById => from ShoutItem item where item.id = :id
INFO  - QueryBinder                - Binding Named query: item.find => from ShoutItem item order by item.timestamp desc
INFO  - QueryBinder                - Binding Named query: item.count => select count(item) from ShoutItem item
INFO  - EntityBinder               - Bind entity com.upbeat.shoutbox.models.ShoutItem on table SHOUT_ITEMS
INFO  - AnnotationConfiguration    - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO  - notationSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO  - earchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
INFO  - ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - RDBMS: HSQL Database Engine, version: 1.8.0
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC driver: HSQL Database Engine Driver, version: 1.8.0
INFO  - Dialect                    - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO  - TransactionFactoryFactory  - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
INFO  - actionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC batch size: 1000
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Connection release mode: auto
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query cache: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
INFO  - FactoryCacheProviderBridge - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query cache factory: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCacheFactory
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Echoing all SQL to stdout
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Statistics: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Named query checking : enabled
INFO  - SessionFactoryImpl         - building session factory
INFO  - essionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO  - UpdateTimestampsCache      - starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
INFO  - StandardQueryCache         - starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
INFO  - notationSessionFactoryBean - Updating database schema for Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO  - Dialect                    - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5dfaf1: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,shoutService,shoutItemDao,wicketApplication,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.34 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.upbeat.shoutbox.integrations.ShoutItemIntegrationTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.upbeat.shoutbox.mocks.ShoutServiceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.01 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  initializationError(com.upbeat.shoutbox.web.TestViewShoutsPage)
  testRenderMyPage(com.upbeat.shoutbox.web.TestHomePage)
  initializationError(com.upbeat.shoutbox.integrations.ShoutItemIntegrationTest)
  initializationError(com.upbeat.shoutbox.mocks.ShoutServiceTest)

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to F:\Projects\shoutbox\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 04 18:19:58 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/31M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `applicationContext-test.xml` overrides the default datasource to supply a Unitils datasource, the `applicationContext.xml` still declares the following property (that gets replaced during Maven filtering):

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
```

So, if you want to run integration tests against an HSQLDB database (Unitils seems to be configured to do so), my understanding is that you are supposed to use the filter [`filters-LOCAL.properties`](https://kenai.com/hg/mystic-apps~mystic-apps/file/bffc68c8b114/mysticpaste/src/main/filters/filters-LOCAL.properties) that is triggered when using the [LOCAL](https://kenai.com/hg/mystic-apps~mystic-apps/file/bffc68c8b114/mysticpaste/pom.xml#l385) profile and declares:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

You can check the `target/classes/applicationContext.xml` to confirm this but it seems obvious that you're not getting the above value but `PostgreSQLDialect`.

The odd part is that the [pom.xml](https://kenai.com/hg/mystic-apps~mystic-apps/file/bffc68c8b114/mysticpaste/pom.xml) of mysticpaste declares the `LOCAL` profile as `activeByDefault` (at least the version in the project repository):

```
<profile>
  <id>LOCAL</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <env>LOCAL</env>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

It should just work. So the question are:

- what does `mvn help:active-profiles` say?
- do you have the this LOCAL profile (and the LOCAL filter)?
- do you have the latest version of this `pom.xml`?

Comment: I have removed the filters that mysticpaste uses in their pom, so I'm not using it. I did this based on an earlier question where it was suggested that I keep away from using filters. 
Instead of these filters I'm using 1 single application.properties file (which contains "hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect").

I'll create the LOCAL filter as you suggested with the appropriate HSQLDialect set :-)

Comment: The suggestion you received here on SO is just one opinion and doesn't necessarily reflect all opinions :) I personally share the point of view expressed by the author of this Wicket series in [this comment](http://www.mysticcoders.com/blog/2009/03/09/5-days-of-wicket-day-1/#comment-1313) and prefer profiles over `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pascal, for the help with the original problem and the note on the use of profiles. Your suggestion of making a profile with the appropriate dialect seems to have done the trick!

Comment: @John To be clear, using a profile to switch from one dialect to another is just one way to go, nothing forces you to use this solution (even if I think profiles are nice). But the fact is that you need to change the value of the `hibernate.dialect` property depending on the environment.

Comment: @Pascal Using profiles seems like a clever choice as I do have several environments (development, testing, pre-production and production). When deploying to the production server, is it enough to use the -P parameter for the deploy command only, or would I need to set the profile containing my production settings to activeByDefault before sending it off to tomcat?

Comment: @John: Dealing with environments is indeed a perfect use case for profiles. Regarding your question, my recommendation would be to not change the `activeByDefault`, use this for the profile that you use the most frequently (very likely a development profile), don't change your pom to release to another environment. Instead, use `-P` when you want another profile (this will disable any profile active by default). Just in case, have a look at the [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).